# Nodejs - Image Buffer size is way larger than the original file

Tags: node.js, image, fs

I need to send a byte array representation of an image from an express server to an android device. After some researches, found this solution

```
const buffer= fs.readFileSync('image_path');
res.send(Uint8Array.from(buffer));
```

It works BUT the size of the sent response is like 3 times higher than the original file (136Ko becomes 487Ko).

Turns out that the it is the size of `buffer`.

Is there a way to fix this so that the sent response matches the original file size? or a better way to send the file to match Java's byte array?